# Is there a word to describe pretending things are alright to not scare children?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I want to say something much more meaningful than what is simply in the title (plus it's a bit long).

This might not be the best example but I find the main character in the movie "Life is Beautiful" exhibits whatever trait this is called perfectly.

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: We still need a sentence.

Comment: Disney.........

Answer (score 2):

The idiom **[put on a brave face](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20on%20a%20brave%20face)** is appropriate:

> to try to appear brave or calm
>
> > She tried to put on/up a brave face/front despite the pain of the injury.

It’s not specific to when you’re trying to protect a child from a harsh reality, but it’s often used in this context:

> [Why your kids know when you’re trying to put on a brave face](https://theconversation.com/why-your-kids-know-when-youre-trying-to-put-on-a-brave-face-154152)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking  for the expression :

***[white lie](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/it/amp/inglese/white-lie)***
(noun [ C ])

> a lie that is told in order to be polite or to stop someone from being upset by the truth.

(Cambridge Dictionary)